# Residues and poles show that

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, residue-calculus

> Show that
>
> i) $\displaystyle\operatorname{Res}\limits_{z=\pi i}\frac{z-\sinh z}{z^2\sinh z}=\frac{i}{\pi}$
>
> ii) $\displaystyle\operatorname{Res}\limits_{z=\pi i}\frac{\exp(zt)}{\sinh z}+ \operatorname{Res}\limits_{z=-\pi i}\frac{\exp(zt)}{\sinh z}=-2\cos(\pi t)$

What I did

i) $\sinh z=\frac{e^z-e^{-z}}{2}\Rightarrow \sinh(2\pi i)=0$ and $f(z)=\frac{z-\sinh z}{z^2\sinh z}=\frac{\phi(z)}{\sinh z}$ where $\phi(z)=\frac{z-\sinh z}{z^2}$ and then $\operatorname{Res}_{z=\pi i}\frac{z-\sinh z}{z^2\sinh z}=\phi(\pi i)=-\frac{i}{\pi}$

What I did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what method you are using but you could try the following.

**Theorem**.  Suppose that $p(z)$ and $q(z)$ are analytic at $z_0$, and $p(z_0)\ne0$ and $q(z_0)=0$ and $q'(z_0)\ne0$.  Then $p(z)/q(z)$ has a simple pole at $z_0$, with residue $p(z_0)/q'(z_0)$.

Taking $z_0=\pi i$ and $p(z)=\frac{z-\sinh z}{z^2}$ and $q(z)=\sinh z$, it is easy to check that the conditions are satisfied, and the residue is
$$\frac{p(z_0)}{q'(z_0)}=\frac{(\pi i-\sinh(\pi i))/(\pi i)^2}{\cosh(\pi i)}
  =\frac{\pi i-0}{(-\pi^2)(-1)}=\frac{i}{\pi}\ .$$